# Redis list with Binary array values instead of strings?

Tags: database, redis, redis-cluster

When I have look at the Redis documentation, I learn that we can use lists for strings (https://redis.io/docs/data-types/lists/).

However, for my use case it would be advantageous, if I could have a list with binary array values stored instead.

I have a few questions regarding that:

- Is such a thing possible?
- If not, is there a workaround?
- Also, say the different binary arrays have size x, does that restrict the number of elements that can be stored in the list if the size x increases?

Comment: Storing binary arrays in list is possible. The number of elements would be restricted by your memory even before Redis' limit.

Comment: @sazzad many thanks for your input. So in theory, I could store several binaries with size 512 mb in one list?

Comment: several binaries, yes. btw, each binary would have a limit. I can recall the limit was either 500 or 512 mb. I'm not sure if it's increased.

Comment: But it is not that the sum has a limit of 512 mb, but each individually, right?

Comment: Yes, each individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest against that setup, if possible. Instead, I would:

- put each (possibly large) binary into its own key, through the `SET` command, naming each key with a hash of the binary data (for example, `file:<CRC32 hash value>`);
- use a list to store just the aforementioned hashes (or the key names).

Key values have a limit of 512MB; lists can have up to 2^32-1 items.